# Cosine related to Bitwise XOR through Repeated Roots

Tags: trigonometry

I have been doing a lot of calculations involving cosine and have noticed a pattern. I spent some time and developed this algorithm for calculating cosines.

To calculate the $\cos(x)$ where $x$ is in radians:

1. Sanitize the input so that $x$ is $[0,2\pi)$:

   $x_1 \gets (|x| \mod 2\pi )$
2. Divide by $\pi$. This is usually fairly trivial as radians are often expressed as multiples of $\pi$.

   $x_2 \gets x_1/\pi$
3. This is where things get interesting. Use the bitwise XOR operation:

   $x_3 \gets x_2 \veebar 2x_2$
4. Here we are going to express $x_3$ in binary and map its bits to signs in a repeated root of 2, which will then be assigned to $x_4$. This is easier to illustrate with an example rather than with a formula:

   [image: Bits to Repeated Root]
5. Finally, divide by 2:

   $x_5 \gets x_4/2$

This will result in the $\cos(x)$, i.e. $\cos(x) = x_5$.

I have used this algorithm quite a lot now, and I am confident that it accurately calculates cosines, but I can't explain why there would be this relationship between cosine and bitwise XOR.

**Why does this relation exist? Can someone please explain why cosines would be related at all to the bitwise XOR operator like this.**

Thanks!

---

### Edit:

For those of you who want a more technical description for step 4, I will need to define some things first:

- A function $D$ that returns the value of a given digit $d$ for a given number $n$ in a given base $b$:

  $$D(n,d,b) = \left \lfloor{n \cdot b^{-d}} \right \rfloor \mod b$$
- A recursive function $f$ that builds repeated roots of 2 with $N$ radicals from the bits of $x$ mapped to the signs:

  $$f(x,n,N) = 
     \begin{cases} 
    0 & n\geq N \\
    (-1)^{D(x,-n,2)}\sqrt{2+f(x,n+1,N)} & n \lt N
     \end{cases}
     $$
- A function $F$ that takes the limits of processing all the bits of $x$ into a repeated root:

  $$F(x) = \lim_{N\to\infty} f(x,0,N)$$

With those defined, step 4 from above would be: $x_4 \gets F(x_3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $\theta \in [0,2)$, let $(b_0.b_1b_2\cdots)_2$ be following binary representation of $\theta$.

$$\theta = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n}
\quad\text{ with }\quad
b_n = {\rm mod}(\lfloor 2^n \theta \rfloor, 2) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$$

Let

- $c_n = b_n \veebar b_{n+1}$
- $\theta_0 = \theta$, $\theta_1 = (b_1.b_2b_3\cdots)_2$, $\theta_2 = (b_2\cdot b_3b_4\cdots)_2, \ldots$
- $\phi_0 = b_0$, $\phi_1 = (b_0.b_1)_2, \ldots, \phi_n = (b_0.b_1b_2\cdots b_n)_2\ldots$

We have
$$
\begin{align}2\cos(\pi\theta) = 2\cos(\pi\theta_0)
&= \sqrt{2 + 2\cos(2\pi\theta_0)} \times 
\begin{cases} 
-1, & \theta_0 \in [\frac12,\frac32)\\
 1, & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}\\
&= (-1)^{b_0+b_1} \sqrt{2+2\cos(\pi(2b_0 + \theta_1))}\\
&= (-1)^{c_0}\sqrt{2+2\cos(\pi\theta_1)}
\end{align}
$$
Repeat this process, we get

$$\begin{align}2\cos(\pi\theta) = &
(-1)^{c_0}\sqrt{2 + 
(-1)^{c_1}\sqrt{2 + 2\cos(\pi \theta_2)}}\\
\vdots\; &\\
= &
(-1)^{c_0}\sqrt{2 + 
(-1)^{c_1}\sqrt{2 + (-1)^{c_2}\sqrt{\cdots (-1)^{c_m} \sqrt{2 + 2\cos(\pi\theta_{m+1})}}}}\tag{*1}\\
\vdots\;&
\end{align}
$$
In this process, if we terminate at step $(*1)$ by replacing $\theta_{m+1}$ with $0$, the value of RHS of $(*1)$ becomes $2\cos(\pi\phi_m)$. 
Since $2\cos(\pi\phi_m) \to 2\cos(\pi\theta)$ as $m \to \infty$, we obtain
following nested radical expansion:

$$2\cos(\pi\theta) =
(-1)^{c_0}\sqrt{2 + 
(-1)^{c_1}\sqrt{2 + (-1)^{c_2}\sqrt{
2 + \cdots
}}}$$

Now take $x_2 = \theta$, then

$$\begin{align}
x_3 &= x_2 \veebar 2x_2 = (b_0c_0.c_1c_2\ldots)_2\\
\text{and}\quad x_4 &= 2\cos(\pi\theta)\\
&\,\Downarrow\\
x_5 &= \frac{x_4}{2} = \cos(\pi x_2) = \cos(x_1) = \cos(|x|) = \cos(x)
\end{align}\\
$$
Aside from the extra rule of ignoring the leading $b_0$ in binary representation of $x_2 \veebar 2x_2$. This is your recipe of computing $\cos(x)$.